How do I format pydoc html output?
I am trying to use pydoc to generate documentation for my code. Basically everything goes smoothly - I input my docstrings and run python -m pydoc on the module and an html file is written.
But the output html file is "plain vanilla" with no nice formatting: white background, no colors to highlite, ugly serif font etc.:

What I am looking for is output formatted like this:

I couldn't find help on how to format the output.
